# fullpage.js in wordpress: scroll-up messes up content position on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js with the "fullpane" theme on my wordpress.

When I open the site on my phone and scroll down, everything looks good and the content containers are where they are supposed to be.
BUT when I scroll up, the position of the content containers is being messed up and they are positioned much higher.

I was able to replicate the problem with multiple browsers (Chrome, Firefox) on Android and iOS and multiple phones.

Interestingly, the problem doesn't persist when I try it in the mobile view of Chrome developer tools.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: They are using an old version of fullPage.js (version 2 vs version 3). Maybe that's why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I refunded the wordpress theme above and created my own theme.